# Set a variable to using in redirected page

Tags: pages, wp-redirect

I need to set a global variable that will be used in the page set on wp_redirect

```
global $open;
$open = FALSE;    

function open_menu($user_login) {
   global $open;
   $open = TRUE;
   wp_redirect(home_url());
   exit;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'open_menu');
```

After redirect, I'm using the variable to open dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown login-dropdown<?php  global $open; if($open == TRUE){echo " open";} ?>">
```

But is not working

Comment: I'm not at all sure what the purpose of such a variable would be but you need to declare your `global` variable outside of your function, declare it again inside your function (for scope) then set it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `wp_login` is executing before functions.php is actually opened, thus not setting the global variable. One possible solution to this is instead append to the URL:

```
function open_menu($user_login) {
    wp_redirect(home_url().'?menu_open=true');
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'open_menu');
```

Then you could get that value via

```
if(isset($_GET['menu_open']) && $_GET['menu_open'])
```